# How to access custom view helper in a partial?

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there a way to access a custom view helper registered in my module like this:

```
'fooBar' => 'Library\FooBar\FooBar'
```

like this?

```
<p>This is partial...</p>
<p><?php echo $this->fooBar(); ?></p>
```

I can use the fooBar view helper in views but in partials I get an error. Here is my view helper:

```
class FooBar extends AbstractHelper
{

    public function __invoke($module)
    {
        return $this->getView()->myMethod();
    }

}
```

And I am getting an error along the lines:

```
Call to a member function myMethod() on a non-object
```

Comment: `<?php echo $this->fooBar(); ?>` should work in your partial, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me. I configure view helper in Module.php file something like this.

//module/src/module/View/Helper/Authz.php
// view helper

```
    use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;



    class Authz extends AbstractHelper 
    {

    public function isAllowed()
{
}
    }
```

.

//Module.php

```
public function bootstrap(Event $e)
    {

    }
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {

        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $app->getServiceManager();


        $serviceManager->get('viewhelpermanager')->setFactory('Authz', function ($sm) use ($e)      {
           return new Authz($sm); //view helper
        });


    }
```

// partial
// view/layout/partials/leftnav.phtml

```
$userAllow = $this->Authz()->isAllowed();
```

// in layout i call above leftnav.phtml partial something like this. 
//view/layout/layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partials/header', array('company_name' => 'CompanyName')); ?>
```

// config/module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'modulename' => __DIR__ . '/../view' ,
        ),
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),

        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'partials/header'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/partials/header.phtml',
            'partials/leftnav'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/partials/leftnav.phtml',            
            'partials/contents-top'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/partials/contents-top.phtml',            
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',    
        ),

    ),
```

Comment: Is that inside a view or a partial? By partial I mean when using the $this->partial() helper to load a subview.

Comment: Try using $this->getView() in your view helper. It will return NULL when you use the helper in the partial. In normal view it will return correct instance...